# Air vs. Water attraction of Oxygen Molecules

Tags: thermodynamics, surface-tension, molecules

The air we breathe is made up of nitrogen and oxygen gases.
The water in a pond is made of a single hydrogen/oxygen molecule.
If it wasn't for the surface tension on top of the water, oxygen molecules can enter the water and occupy space next to the hydrogen/oxygen molecules.

My question is this:  All things being equal, is oxygen more attracted to water or air?

Answer (score 2):

At 5 °C, the maximum amount of oxygen dissolved in water is 12.8 ppm[[1]](http://www.ecy.wa.gov/programs/wq/plants/management/joysmanual/dissolvedoxygen.html). This is much less than the 21% oxygen in the air. It is not the surface tension that limits the amount of oxygen dissolving into the water, but the limited solubility of the oxygen in the water.